# How can I escape colons in Django's field lookups?

Tags: django

I've brought some JSON metadata into a `JSONfield()` and some of the key names include a colon. Am I able to escape the field lookups so I can do something like the example below?

```py
filtered_qs = queryset.filter(data__properties__object:key="some_value")
```

where `object:key` is the name of my JSON key

Currently i'm getting the `keyword cannot be an expression` syntax error.

I'm using Postgres 11.2 and Django 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary expansion:

```
filtered_qs = queryset.filter(**{"data__properties__object:key": "some_value"})
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't escape the colon in this situation.

You can however achieve the same result using the [contains lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-hstorefield.contains).

```
filtered_qs = queryset.filter(data__properties__contains={'object:key': 'some_value'})
```

Comment: This is a good option as well, but I need to also use comparison operators. Thanks though.